# Silverlight and VS2008 installation issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight-3.0

I have installed VS 2008 and Silverlight with version as

**Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP and Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1**

**Microsoft Silverlight Projects 2008 Version 9.0.30730.126**

I can see the Silverlight project in the File – New Project menu, however as soon as I click on the Silverlight project....

I get following error

> **Microsoft Silverlight tool is unable to open the project due to a missing patch for a Visual Studio, please download latest
> updates from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=143751**

I checked with this link also but sln given is not working.